# Screen gets stuck in white color when running Flutter app

Tags: flutter

My screen gets stuck in white color while  run the app.i m using vivo phone
its shows

```
I/flutter (10711): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
I/flutter (11716): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
I/flutter (15564): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
```

I am trying all the methods:

- restart the phone
- restart the computer
- reinstall flutter sdks.

but still got an error. How can I solve the error?

Comment: Please check formatting of your question: maybe it needs some line separations

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information? As it is still unclear what exactly is going wrong.

Maybe you haven't assigned good amount of ram to your android device. By default android studio does not assign large amount of ram to the device and which cause issues when we run our projects as it has very limited hardware resources. Try increasing the ram of the emulator device and it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am having vivo Y35, and that problems occurs on my device too, I tried set all things like

- Revoke USB Debugging
- Check and Uncheck verify apps over usb
- Changing log debug sizes
- using #5501(or something i forgot the exact guides), it wont work as well.

To be direct, all things i tried didn't work.
My device once be like this on the previous time and it works when the os upgrade to funtouch 12.

But now after funtouch version updated to 13, it crash again. IT IS FROM JANUARY 2023 AND UNTIL THIS MOMENT (June 2023) THEY DIDN'T EVEN BOTHER TO SOLVE THAT UNLESS WE CONTACT THEIR DEVELOPER FROM THEIR WEBSITE(which is still in mandarin language).

It is seem from the port from vivo won't open to be debugable.

Note : You can try any other Phone than Vivo or iQoo, they just works right out of the box when you set developer mode on.

And my suggestion, let's stop using Vivo and iQoo for flutter development, Just don't buy the same brand again.

This, changed my mind that vivo is my favourite android device.